# Supercapacitors for transient power-out for RPi

Tags: raspberry-pi, ups, supercapacitor

So I found a RPi Hat (https://juice4halt.com/products) with supercapacitors as a short term UPS for RPi, however it's on the pricey side. I don't necessarily need the communication with the RPi to do power-off detection or what not, just need some brief power-loss detection for 5 or 10 seconds.

Can I just put a couple of bare supercapacitors in-line with the 5V input, no other circuitry/resistors/etc needed? Or is there more supporting components that I need?

Comment: How much does Rpi consume current, and how low voltage can drop from 5V to keep it running? If you know those, you can calculate how much capacitance you need.

Comment: Let's call it 500mA is my estimate on max, and by that I mean well beyond what I think the normal, nominal usage. I think 1-2W is more likely the usual with what I'm running. As for voltage drop-off, good question, but better to keep it +/- .25v I think, but that's just my off the cuff thought, I have no real actual clue. It's going in through the usual 5v mUSB port, so it has voltage regulator on it so it might just start pulling a bit more power if the voltage sags to regulate it up to 5v.

Comment: Great. 0.5A, 5 seconds, 0.25V drop. That's 10F.

Comment: Thanks, but I was more asking, first, I can just simply put those inline on the 5v +, right? No additional components needed?

Comment: I don't think connecting 10F directly to 5V input makes a lot of sense. It takes 50 seconds for the voltage to rise from 0V to 5V at 1A charging current. Such amount of supercaps can be pricey. Perhaps a USB powerbank with support for supply pass-thru is cheaper?

Comment: You will need current limiting to avoid blowing up whatever you plug the device into.

Comment: Thanks both of you, some good points. Would definitely be more involved than I was hoping *sigh*  Guess that's also why they charge a fair bit for their device. I think their design is open, so maybe I'll see if I can come up with a simpler, cheaper circuit and DIY it.

Answer (score 1):

Batteries vs Capacitors for capacity vs lifetime cost.

There are many variables. But In general terms, yours are infrequent demand for UPS not daily or hourly, I assume.

Capacitors vs Rechargeable

- Ic=CdV/dt or Icdt/dV=C
- for Li Ion with 2.4Ah capacity 2.4Ah*3600 s/h= 8640 A-s
- 3.8V Li Ion with dV=0.8V ,
- C = 8640A-s / 0.8V almost 10k Farads! But limited charge cycles 350 but OK for UPS mode as req’d.

vs.

- Ultracap 0.5A drain for 2sec with dV= 0.8V C=Ic*dt/dV=0.5*2/0.8V=1.25 Farads but >100k charge cycles but shorts out supply to charge up again due low ESR (mOhm) and depending on supply may cutoff or overheat or be ok(?)

### Conclusion

Li Ion or Li Po may be better suited on float charge 3.6V than an Ultracap.

Verify : what are your assumptions?

If you reply on 5V input, then your best bet may be a 5V Li-Ion bank for >>10 s of reliable backup and keep it on float charge with current limit.